# What is this door hardware called?

Tags: doors, lock, hinges

Can someone help me out and let me know what these are called?

I'm looking on a DIY site to order one but can't work out what these are called to be able to find them.

As you can see in the picture, it's loosened over the years and now doesn't pull the door tight (it also looks broken to me as the bottom part is 'inside' the top - can someone confirm?), so I need to get a replacement.

[image]

Comment: Well, it's a spring catch of some sort. Try finding a manufacturer's name on it and contact them for advice.

Comment: Try sending a picture to the folks at Blane Window Hardware http://www.blainewindow.com/index.php. They have helped me identify parts in the past for windows / doors.

Comment: Can we get another picture... like of the other half of the latch? Is this for a sliding (screen) door? I'm thinking it's some kind of knuckle catch for a sliding screen door.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a push latch or a push to close latch for sliding doors- like the one pictured below:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an old style door catch. There are many different versions of these available. Too many to list. The most common are spring rollers and magnets. Home Improvement stores will have a bunch of different styles. Choose the one that works best for your application.

Common Name: Door Catch, Catch, Cabnet Catch, etc.